# Windows 8 Desktop background lock orientation

Tags: windows-8, desktop-customization, display-rotation

I have chosen a desktop background and I am having a beef with it because when I rotate the desktop, so does the background. I wonder how its possible change settngs so that the desktop background image does not rotate as my tablet?